# How to dynamically position a IonPopover to appear from a button?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, popover, ionic-react

I'm trying to position a popover to appear underneath a button when that button is clicked. An example of this is on the Ion docs page. [image]

However the code for this is not supplied in React, only in Angular.

Currently my code looks like this

```
...
<IonButtons slot="end">
                        <IonButton onClick={() => setShowPopover(true)} expand="block">
                            <IonIcon icon={more}/>
                        </IonButton>
                    </IonButtons>
                    <IonPopover
                        isOpen={showPopover}
                        backdropDismiss={true}
                        onDidDismiss={() => setShowPopover(false)}>
                        <IonItem>Popover Item</IonItem>
                    </IonPopover>
...
```

The popover is toggled by the button above it. When the button is pressed the popover appears in the middle of the page, not over the button. How do I change this so the popover is shown attached to the button? (Like the image)

Thanks

Comment: did you implemented the close button to close the popover when you click it ? please provide your code or how you did it ? I want to do this with react but there is absolutely nothing about how to do this in the docs or in the internet

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inspired by the answer of Thomas but unable to make his code work the following did the trick for me:

```
const [showPopover, setShowPopover] = useState<{open: boolean, event: Event | undefined}>({
  open: false,
  event: undefined,
});

<IonPopover
    isOpen={showPopover.open}
    event={showPopover.event}
    onDidDismiss={e => setShowPopover({open: false, event: undefined})}
>
   <p>This is popover content</p>
</IonPopover>
<IonButton onClick={(e) => setShowPopover({open: true, event: e.nativeEvent})}>Click</IonButton>
```

Comment: Perfect, this works how I want it to. I think it was the event passing I was missing. Solved.

Comment: Thanks! The key for me was recognizing that it needs the `nativeEvent`

Comment: Kudos for using Typescript

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover#presenting):

> To present a popover, call the present method on a popover instance. In order to position the popover relative to the element clicked, a click event needs to be passed into the options of the the present method. If the event is not passed, the popover will be positioned in the center of the viewport.

So you need to pass the click event to the popover's `event` property.

I've never looked at React, but you might be able to add it to the state:

Updated example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { IonPopover, IonButton } from '@ionic/react';

export const PopoverExample: React.FC = () => {
  const [showPopover, setShowPopover] = useState<{open: boolean, event: Event | null}>({
    open: false,
    event: null,
  });

  return (
    <>
      <IonPopover
        isOpen={showPopover.open}
        event={showPopover.event}
        onDidDismiss={e => setShowPopover({open: false, event: null})}
      >
        <p>This is popover content</p>
      </IonPopover>
      <IonButton onClick={(e) => setShowPopover({open: true, event: e})}>Show Popover</IonButton>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Do you have an example of passing a click event? Not something that I have done yet in React, thanks.

Comment: I've added a possible example but I've never used React, so it might be completely wrong 

Comment: Seems like there's an issue with typescript and setting the event to type 'null'. changing to 'undefined' hasn't solved it yet, hmm

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. Will have to keep looking for a work around